# LinearLayoutManager (LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) don't work

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontal-scrolling

I want to use the horizontal scroll recycler.

For this, I use LinearLayoutManager (LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL), this works, but different indentation is obtained for the items.

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqp8A.png

Layout for fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_related"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_2_lenta"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for item:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#ff0">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**UPD**

Creating a layoutManager

```
vRelatedStub.setOnInflateListener((viewStub, sView) -> {
    vLabelRelated = sView.findViewById(R.id.label_related);
    vListRelated = sView.findViewById(R.id.list_related);
    vLoaderRelated = createLoaderView(sView, mAdapterRelated);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    vListRelated.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    vListRelated.setAdapter(mAdapterRelated);
});
vRelatedStub.inflate();
```

Comment: This is probably because you are wrapping the height of the MaterialCardView based on the content. So from what I can see from screenshot you provided, since the second item has three lines of text, it has bigger height. As a result, you are seeing cards of different height. Solution would be to assign the "minLine" and "maxLine" value for the textview holding the text. This way, irrespective of content size, the textview will have uniform height throughout the recyclerview.

Comment: @Azhar92 In fact, there are 3 lines everywhere, but even if I set a fixed height for the MaterialCardView, but the problem remains. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xprid.png

Comment: Can you share the code where you assign value to your layout manager?

Comment: @Shubham I added creation code to description

Answer (score 0):

Found an error in my code.
The thing was that I asked margin to the first item in the bind holdar,
this remained from the vertical linear manager.